# Finding sets in a list of sets that are subsets and select them

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, list-comprehension, slice

I would like to select only those sets from a list of sets that are subsets of another set, so essentially that:

```
sets = [{1, 2, 3}, {6, 7, 8}]
s = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
list(compress(sets, [sub <= s for sub in sets]))
```

This works but it feels wrong to first evaluate the list comprehension and afterwards using compress. Is there a way to index *sets* directly, like:

```
sets[[sub <= s for sub in sets]] ### This does not work!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[i for i in sets if all(j in s for j in i)]
```

Test:

```
In [226]: sets = [{1, 2, 3}, {6, 7, 8}, {1,2}, {3}, {7,1}, {7,8}, {8}]
In [227]: s = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}

In [228]: [i for i in sets if all(j in s for j in i)]
Out[228]: [{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {3}, {1, 7}]
```